# Can an adverb modify an adverb

Tags: adverbs

Can an adverb modify an adverb?

I have heard “extremely carefully” used by a friend as in the sentence:

> The plane was extremely carefully repaired.

Is that correct?

Comment: When I typed `What do adverbs modify` into Google, the top of the page said: _Words that modify verbs, adjectives, or adverbs are adverbs. **Definition**: An adverb modifies a verb, adjective, or another adverb._ In the future, try to do at least a modicum of research before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, Yes!

You can use an adverb to describe another adverb. In fact, if you wanted to, you could use several.

See [Grammarly's blog about adverbs](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/).